# Ruby on Rails: When to add a new resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function, model-view-controller, resources

I have two questions on how the MVC works. I'm pretty sure I should add several resources, but I'm just coming to this conclusion and wanted to ask first to get a better understanding.

**First question:** 
I have two models, user and subject. Users can enter subjects into the database. For each subject there are 5 data entry forms (Baseline, 3month, 6month,...) that are about 100-200 questions each (The relationship would be each subject has 1 of each data entry form). Should each data entry form be a new resource?

**Second Question:** 
Lets say I want to randomize a few subjects into a group:

From the view, the user enters the amount of subjects to be randomized into a group, as well as the group name to be assigned. The form tag specifies an action I created, just for this function, called randomize.

From the controller, randomize uses the params sent from the view to query the database, and then to update each record to reflect the group. Instead of creating a new action for the randomize function, should I create a new resource for it? And as a side note, should any of these calculations be done in the model (other than defining the variables)?

Thank you for your time. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am officially over-whelmed by all of the information I'm learning about this...but I feel that I'm really close to actually understanding the MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer your second question first.

You should be creating controllers to handle CRUD tasks for resources. In this question you ask about creating a "Group". Regardless of whether this is an actual resource, or just a modification to a collection of other resources, you have the concept of creating a "Group", probably reading/updating a "group" and certainly deleting one.

Based on this, I would rather have a `RandomGroup` controller which I can call using a standard REST interface, rather than some `#randomize` action stuffed in the side of another controller.

As for your first question ... maybe, maybe not.
It really depends on whether an data entry form has any business logic of its own. If it doesn't then there's no harm it being part of a large object. But if your tests and code start to become too complex within the Subject model you may want to split it out into multiple models or at least multiple modules included into that model.

Perhaps you could consider that "Baseline", "3month", "6month" are all the same ... aside from their lead time. Perhaps that is a model in itself, and `Subject` could `has_many :forms` ??

Food for thought.